# Access denied error in Azure devops CI CD deployment

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, spfx

Below are the detailed steps which i am performing for CI CD created pipeline to create spkg.sppkg its successful now in release i am doing below steps

```
Connect to SharePoint App Catalog (Successful)

o365 login https://naxis007.sharepoint.com/sites/Wipro%20App%20Catalog/AppCatalog --authType password --userName $(username) --password $(password)

Add Solution Package to App Catalog **(getting error access denied in this steps)** 
o365  spo app add -p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Test/drop/drop/sharepoint/solution/spfx.sppkg --overwrite --appCatalogUrl https://naxis007.sharepoint.com/sites/Wipro%20App%20Catalog/AppCatalog --scope sitecollection
```

[image]

Comment: It's not a question of what role *you* have, it's a question of the role(s) assigned to your service connection's service principal object. That said, please provide more detail - your post cuts off so much information you're forcing people to guess at your problem.

Comment: i tried to provide steps please let me know if any further information required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were running `o365 login` command and `o365  spo app add` command in two separate `command line tasks`.

Each `command line task` will open a new terminal window which will be closed when the task is finished. So the login information in the first `command line task` cannot persist in the second `command link task`. That's why you got the access denied error.

You should run the `o365 login` command and `o365  spo app add` command in the same `command line task`. So that both the commands will be executed in the same terminal.

Or you can use the task [SharePoint Files Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=projectumapsvsts.upload-sp-files-app&ssr=false#qna) to upload the spfx.sppkg file .